# Passing property through router

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is for a react-native app

I'm trying to pass a property to a component through a router like so:

I have a button with an onPress like so in separate component:

```
  _onPress() {
    this.props.navigator.push(Router.getDealList(this.state.categoryName, this.state.categoryId));
  }
```

With the router defined as:

```
const Router = {
  getDealList(categoryName, categoryId) {
    return {
      renderScene() {
        let DealList = require('./components/DealList').default;
        debugger;
        return <DealList categoryId={categoryId} />;
      },
      getTitle() {
        return categoryName;
      },
    };
  },
};
```

However, when I try to access the property in the DealList component, it seems to be undefined. I am attempting to do this like so:

```
  _onFetch(page = 1, callback) {
    const categoryId = this.props.categoryId;
...
}
```

I've attempted to debug this and it seems to have the variables up until the point where I try to call `_onFetch`

Answer (score 0):

I have used a different approach in my React native app. Please be patient, this might give you a clue or you can adopt the same way altogether.

In `main.js` I have this structure which takes care of everything smoothly.

Top level views:

```
var Splash = require('./views/splash');
var Signin = require('./views/signin');
var Signup = require('./views/signup');
var Home = require('./views/home');
```

Routes:

```
var ROUTES = {
    splash: Splash,
    signin: Signin,
    signup: Signup,
    home: Home,
};
```

And navigator looks something like this. Observe "data" being passed as a prop to respective `Component` in `renderScene()`

```
render: function(){

    return(
        //Render first view through initialRoute
        <Navigator 
            style={styles.container} 
            initialRoute={{ name: 'home', index: 0 }} 
            renderScene={ this.renderScene } 
            configureScene={ () => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight; }}
        >
        </Navigator>            
    )
},
renderScene: function(route, navigator){

    //ROUTES['signin'] => SignIn
    var Component = ROUTES[route.name]; 
    return (
        <Component 
            route={route} 
            navigator={navigator} 
            data={route.data}
        />
    );      
}
```

When I want to push a new View in my app I simply do this-

```
onPressNewBooking: function(){
    this.props.navigator.push({ name: 'newbooking', data: this.state.rawData })
}
```